# Update or insert element into xml column dependent on existence

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, xpath, sql-update

I'm trying to write an update statement that checks if an element exists in an XML column, and updating it's value if it exists. If not it will then insert the value as a new element.

Something like:

```
UPDATE Table
SET xmlCol = 
case
when xmlCol.exist('element') = 1
then xmlCol.modify('replace value of blah')
else xmlCol.modify('insert blah')
end
where whatever
```

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The modify() method of the xml data type can only be used in the SET clause of an UPDATE statement.

It's probably simplest to do it in two statements.

```
UPDATE Table 
SET xmlCol.modify('replace value of /blah')
WHERE xmlCol.exist('/blah') = 1;

UPDATE Table
SET xmlCol.modify('insert /blah')
WHERE xmlCol.exist('/blah') = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the modify method. This is a good alternative. What do you think would be more efficient, this or selecting the column into a variable and then using an if statement to call the correct update statement?

Comment: It might be faster to do the insert first, then do the replace on the entire table leaving off the WHERE clause and saving the cost of one exist check. I think you'd have to write a procedure to be able to use your IF THEN ELSE logic.

Comment: I ended up using if statements, mostly out of personal preference, but this is a perfectly acceptable answer.